# Can I use a worksheet as a function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a worksheet set up such that I can input a value, do some math to give me a bunch of values, repeat math a few times, and add up all the values and return an output value. It is complex enough that it would impractical to copy and pasted all the cells every time I test a new input. It was fine when I had to test 2 or 3 different parameters, but now that I need to test 50 different inputs and create a graph I need some help.

Is there some way I can create a table with the 50 input values, somehow input them into the worksheet, and get the output values so I can make a graph? Options using vb-script could work.

EDIT: I have included the majority of the calculations, where the value in A2 is the input value, and the value in D10 is the output value. See [below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0PXR.png)

[image]

Comment: You would have to give us an example, from the way your question currenly reads I can't understand why simply copy/paste replication of formulas down columns or across rows would not fill your needs.

Comment: What formulas are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is to use vba to input all the values into proper cells let excel do the calculations and copy the results out using something like the macro below.  I've put an image of the test sheet below.  Obviously yours would be more in depth and you would probably put the table on a different sheet then you calculations.  Formula in G5 was sum(G2:G4).  No formulas in column D that is where the results get stored.

```
Sub get_data()
Dim dataA As Double, dataB As Double, dataC As Double, dataOutput As Double
Dim lastRow As Long, currentRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
        'Read in data from table
        dataA = .Range("A" & currentRow).Value
        dataB = .Range("B" & currentRow).Value
        dataC = .Range("C" & currentRow).Value

        'Put data into worksheet
        .Range("G2").Value = dataA
        .Range("G3").Value = dataB
        .Range("G4").Value = dataC

        'You could also avoid the variables by putting it directly into the cell without variable
        '.Range("G2").Value = .Range("A" & currentRow).Value
        'etc

        Calculate

        'store results in variable
        dataOutput = .Range("G5").Value

        'Put results back in table
        .Range("D" & currentRow).Value = dataOutput
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use data tables in Excel for this:

1. You list your inputs in a row or column (so they represent a table axis).
2. Then go "What-If Analysis" > "Data Table".
3. The wizard prompts you for the input and output fields. It then pastes the output value for each input next to each input.